Assigning points based on quartiles (percentiles) according to a grouped virtual table
Good day to all!
I have a table with tasks that one or another counterparty (person) performs
My task is:

Group the data by counterparty and how many tasks he completed
Find the value of 25% 50% 75% percentile in this table
Based on the found percentile data, assign your score to the counterparty

if the number of tasks is less than 25% percentile- 1 point
if the number of tasks is less than 50% percentile- 2 points
if the number of tasks is less than 75% percentile- 3 points
if the number of tasks is more than 75% percentile- 4 points




I created this measure, I don't understand why it gives 0 everywhere
Points based on the volume of tasks = 
VAR table1= CALCULATETABLE(GROUPBY('RTO_RegionMountView2',RTO_RegionMountView2[Контрагент],"Counttasks",COUNTAX(CURRENTGROUP(),VALUE('RTO_RegionMountView2'[task]))),FILTER('RTO_RegionMountView2','RTO_RegionMountView2'[Contragent]<>BLANK()))

VAR p25 =
    PERCENTILEX.INC (table1,[Counttasks],0.25 )
VAR p50 =
    PERCENTILEX.INC (table1,[Counttasks],0.5 )
VAR p75 =
    PERCENTILEX.INC (table1,[Counttasks],0.75 )
RETURN
    IF(SUMX(table1,[Counttasks])<p25,1,IF(SUMX(table1,[Counttasks])<p50,2,IF(SUMX(table1,[Counttasks])<p75,3,IF(SUMX(table1,[Counttasks])>p75,4,0))))

Another very important point is that this measure can be dynamically changed in accordance with these filters in power bi
help to identify the error)))
Data link
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qGwR4nBeHP5e2VDfr6zh_pRAj3U6oE4V/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106212180587000488164&rtpof=true&sd=true

Can we have some data ?

I have attached the appeal below.
I will need to make slices in Power Bi by Date
Tabular grouping by counterparty and number of tasks

I have an issue with your date column can you please format it properly as I lack knowledge in Russian
